# How to write spec to test that search works if query is passed in?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

Hi I'm trying to write a couple Rspec tests and struggling a bit.

I have an index page listing out transactions, and I've created a search box to let you find transactions by ID or user name or user email.

Now I'm trying to write a spec to ensure the search works if a query is passed in. Here's the relevant part of controller action:

```
def index
  @title = "Payments"

  if params[:query]
    @payments = Payment.text_search(params[:query])
  else
```

Here's my attempt at writing the associated test: 
(**EDIT** the search works in browser but i'm trying to write some specs and just very new to rspec so not sure what the right approach is.)

```
it "payments search works with a query" do
  user = FactoryGirl.create(:user, name: 'Space Cat', email: 'foo@bar.com')
  login_to_admin
  get :index, :query => 'space cat'
  response.status.should == 200
  response.body.should match(/foo@bar.com/)
  response.body.should include(user)
end
```

Any tips?

Comment: What's the specific issue? Are you saying the test works? Doesn't work? Doesn't test what you want?

Comment: @DaveNewton the search works fine in a browser. i'm fairly new (overall, but particularly with rspec) so i want to write some specs but struggling to understand the right approach. will update the post to clarify. thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A controller spec should just check that what happens is expected:

```
let(:query) { 'space cat' }
let(:search_result) { double 'search_result', :paginate => [] }

before do
  login_to_admin
end

it "payments search works with a query" do
  Payment.should_receive(:text_search).with(query).and_return search_result
  get :index, :query => query
  expect(assigns(:payments)).to eq []
end
```

Your mistakes were:

- depending on implementation: you must spec `Payment.text_search` in a model spec
- depending on view: you should not bother how you display data in a controller spec
- create useless objects in db: because of your former dependencies, you were compelled to create a user in db which is pointless and time consuming

Comment: thanks man -- quick follow up -- the spec breaks on the index page's pagination. do you know why that is? `Failure/Error: get :index, :query => query
       Double "search result" received unexpected message :paginate with ({:page=>nil, :per_page=>50})`

Comment: bottom of the controller action: `respond_to do |format| format.html { @payments = @payments.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 50)}`

Comment: sorry to hassle you. w. ur fix it still breaks on paginate: `Failure/Error: get :index, :query => query \NoMethodError: undefined method 'paginate' for #<Array:0x007fbd054804f8>`

Comment: i'll accept ur answer. for what it's worth, even w ur last edit, i got `Diff:#<ActiveRecord::Relation:0x007fe6ef1dd9f8>.==(#<ActiveRecord::Relation:0x007fe6ef129480>) returned false even though the diff between #<ActiveRecord::Relation:0x007fe6ef1dd9f8> and #<ActiveRecord::Relation:0x007fe6ef129480> is empty. Check the implementation of #<ActiveRecord::Relation:0x007fe6ef1dd9f8>.==.` i did however get it to pass with the following last line: `response.body.should match(/query/)` (does that even make sense as a test?)

Comment: to make it cleaner, even pagination should be stubbed.so lets do this, edited again

Comment: The selected answer doesn't really answer the question, it just sets forth an opinion on how to do testing. What the original poster needed was to check the content of a rendered view, not write "a controller spec". At least @chhhris answered his own question on the comment above (`response.body.should match(/query/)`)